# Compile an external own project in Visual Studio

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, typescript

I have a folder representing my typescript project. In this folder there are other sub folders: one sub folder contains many classes (.ts, typescript source files), another one contains samples (.html files) and a javascript library, etc. The samples work correctly, just with right click on .html file and "open with --> browser". Now I want to open this project in Visual Studio, for developing other stuffs and to make everything simpler. I tried to import my project selecting **File--> New --> Project from existing code**. The .csproj and .sln files have been successfully created in my folder , I can open my project in Visual Studio and and compiling is successful. Again, if a try to open the samples created (in Visual Studio), they work fine, just with right click and "view in browser". However, if I open my typescript files, they have many errors due to references (i.e. a class Dog extends Animal, and the error is under Animal, it says "***Cannot find name 'Animal'*** ". What's wrong in my import?

Comment: Check the build actions for the files (click the file in solution explorer, look in the properties window [usually F4]). These indicate to VS how it should treat them

Comment: @Basic in the File Properties I have just "File Name", "Absolute Path", "Build Action" (set to TypeScriptCompile) and "Copy to Output Directory" (set to 'do not copy'). Something wrong?

Comment: No, that's what I'd hope (specifically the build action is set to compile which means it should be considered by the compiler and therefore be available for linking)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using "Project from existing code", create a new "TypeScript HTML" project (you can find it by typing "TypeScript" into the search box in the new project dialog) .

Delete all of the default contents, then paste in your HTML and TypeScript files.

If you paste them into the directory, you can view them in Visual Studio by selecting "Show Hidden Files" and then right click them and select "Include".

This will ensure your project comes pre-populated with the TypeScript options, which you can customise in "Project > Properties > TypeScript".

Comment: it seems to work fine. I'm just wondering why the other way doesn't  evaluate references. Thank you anyway !

Comment: Because the project is missing some settings - if you do a diff on the project file you'll the differences.